# Are Arab Israelis permitted to purchase land in the West Bank?

Tags: real-property, israel, palestine

It seems that [Palestinian land laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palestinian_land_laws) prohibit Palestinians from selling any Palestinian-owned lands to "any man or judicial body corporation of Israeli citizenship, living in Israel or acting on its behalf". Do Arab Israelis, living on land that has been part of the Israeli state since 1948 (for example, Arabs living in the city of Haifa), fall under that prohibition?